# Generating random locations for different-sized non-overlapping quadrangles in a 2D area

Tags: jquery, algorithm, random

I am looking for an algorithm to generate random locations for different-sized non-overlapping quadrangles in a 2D area. an example can be:
 [image]

The random size of the quadrangles is between a*a and b*b and they are parallel to xy coordinates. I am using JQuery (javaScript).

--If I generate two independent random numbers (for x and y coordinates) for each rectangle, I have to check if the new rectangle in this location does not overlap with the other existing rectangles. and if it does, ignore this selection and generate a new pair of  numbers (a new location). Hence, maybe this is not a good algorithm--

Does anybody have any suggestions? 
Thanks.

Comment: I love the smell of homework in the morning

Comment: Does it have to be *truly* random or would a random-ish version do?

Comment: OK. Cool question, I'm surprised this isn't getting more attention! If you don't have a definitive answer after my exam, I'll work on one and post it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a quadtree or a kd-tree to subdivide the surface. A spatial index can work too. Look for space filling curve and spatial index and quadkey or geohash how to find a quadrant. Maybe a r-tree is also good because space filling curve is very complex. Here is bing map quadkey example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx. Then you can randomly use a breadth-first search.

Comment: Thanks. your answer was very good. However, I was looking for a more practical, less complex solution. Finally, I just removed the space allocated to each character from the 'free space' and try to locate the next character randomly in the remaining 'free space'.

Comment: I don't understand a thing but it's very close to a k-d tree. r-tree or quadtree. You should learn one of them it's easier to speak together and you don't need to reinvent the wheel.